# Determining Big O of a loop with a break

Tags: javascript, big-o

Given a function like this to find a prime number:

```
function find_the_prime(number) {
  var found = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if(number%i == 0) {
      found = true; 
      break;
    }
  }  
  return found;
}
```

Without the break, the function in the best case is O(1), in the worst case is O(n) and the general case O(n).

Can you explain how the break affects big o? Does it at all?

Comment: This is not homework btw, this is just a curious engineer who wants to get better with Big O.

Comment: I think it's the worst case scenario with big O's. `O(n)`.

Comment: number%0 ? Divide by zero error :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Computer Science and belongs on [cs.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is O(1) for the trivial reason that it will always quit on the second loop because number%1 == 0.

If you correct your code to:

```
for(var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
```

Then it'll be O(n) for the same reason the @zmf said.

And without the break, it would more correctly be called `O(n)` even for the "best-case" because it still scales with the input. The smallest input isn't "best-case" or else all algorithms would be trivially best-case `O(1)`.

So it's `O(n)` without the break and `O(n)` with the break, but that doesn't mean it isn't obviously better and faster with the break. The big-O notation is about how an algorithm scales with the size of the input, not (necessarily) how fast it is. Sometimes an `O(n)` algorithm might be faster than an `O(log n)` algorithm for a particular input.

Comment: Wouldn't it then just be O(3)?

Comment: @Kith: No. The `1` in `O(1)` refers to it being *constant time*, it's not a count of how many times it goes through the loop. If you loop 10 times regardless of the size of the input, you'd still be `O(1)`.

Comment: @Kith: No. Because larger values of *n* will loop more often. Best case they are even and exit early, worse case you have to try every value up to *n-1*. The algorithm the OP is using is not very good because it will test, for example `2` and `4` even though if it's not divisible by `2` it can't be divisible by `4`.

Comment: Don't mind me. I wasn't reading the function well. Thanks. I just assumed the function was finding the small prime number in a range from 0 to N)

Comment: @Kith When you think of O notation, the size of N is irrelevant. Size of N may have other performance issues, but when discussing O, remember that saying something is O(N) means the amount of processing required to execute this function will grow linearly. An O(1) algorithm will remain constant based on N, and O(n^2) means for every increase of N, your function will take twice as long!

Comment: Right. I said what I said because  I just assumed the function was finding the smallest prime number in a range from 0 to N. I feel like that would be linear (assuming n > 2) because the smallest prime would be 3

Answer (score 2):

This is still O(N), even if thats the worst case, O(N) is how you'd refer to this algorithm. Its growth rate is still dependent on N.

(If you fix the bug that is)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, funny enough, your answer is O(1). No matter what number you put in (as long as it's > 0), it'll always break at 1